# Import "discord" could not be resolved error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord

I'm trying to make a discord bot, and I keep getting this error:
`Import "discord" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)`

I used this to install the package:
`py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py`

I am using the cmd on Visual Studio Code for this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Package names don't usually end in `.py`.  Are you sure that was the exact command?

Comment: @JohnGordon The docs for discord.py say that that is the command for Windows. Here is the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#) that I [used](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)

Comment: The usual reason for this error is that you have multiple versions of python installed on your system. pip installed the module for one version, but VS code is using a different version.

Comment: Show us the output of this command `py -3 -m pip --version` and this code `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry for the wait, these are the result. Result of the command:
`pip 22.2.2 from C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)`


Result of the code:
`3.9.11 (main, Mar 18 2022, 16:54:01)  [GCC 11.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: That's the reason.  Pip installed the package for Python 3.10, but VS Code is using Python 3.9.11.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Run VS Code as administrator > Navigate to your project path in the Terminal (CMD) in VS Code > Then Run the command `py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py`
2. If Step 1 doesn't work, Open the Command Prompt as administrator from the Windows System (Not in VS Code) > Navigate to the project path & Run that same command.

- And then restart the VS Code and check!

Note: Make Sure you have installed the latest [Python 3.x](https://www.python.org/downloads/) version

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use the following command to install the **discord** package.

```
pip install discord
```

Secondly, maybe there are multiple python environments on your machine, please use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette, then search and select **Python:Select Interpreter**, and select the correct interpreter.

[image]

[image]

***There are two ways to be right here***

- Select the interpreter environment where you successfully installed the **discord** package earlier
- Choose an interpreter environment you want to use, then create a new terminal to activate the environment, and install the **discord** package for your new environment.

Comment: The installation for `pip install discord` failed

Comment: Can you provide error information?